# ksh + print the same format as param

Tags: ksh

the following script print the $line parameter
my target is to print the numbers in the $line exactly as they described
 as  the following

example1

```
   12435345645645645
   6564564564565
   655656565
```

But the script print like that

12435345645645645 6564564564565 655656565

What need to change in the script in order to get the print as example1 (without to change $line parameter)

the scrip.ksh

```
 #!/bin/ksh


 line=' 12435345645645645
        6564564564565
        655656565'
```

print $line

./script.ksh

```
 12435345645645645 6564564564565 655656565
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to add "\n" on the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around the variable to preserve the newlines:

```
print "$line"
```